# can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32

Tags: python, numpy

train_labels = torch.tensor(train_labels)

I tried to to torch tenser a train_labels but it give me the same warning

and the président code works fine and give good results but I need to understand this warning :

```
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.
```

thanks for help

Comment: Take a look at `train_labels.dtype`.  Apparently it is `dtype('O')`, which is the *object* data type.  It means the elements of the array are actually pointers to Python objects, instead of one of the fundamental numerical types shown in the error message.  You'll have to convert the array to a numerical type, or fix how it is created to avoid creating an object array in the first place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: An array with `object` dtype probably was produced from a list of arrays that vary in shape.  Review the `shape` and `dtype` of the array you are using.

Comment: yes it's dtype('o')    i put this line before torch tenser ( train_inputs, test_inputs, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(input_ids, labels, 
                                                           test_size=1 - train_ratio))    to splite the data so How can i apdate it to numerical type